# Can the banner on Beta sites be closable?

Tags: feature-request, design, private-beta, notification-bar

I joined a site in Private Beta, and there is a banner at the top of the page. Here's a screenshot of it (laptop)

[image: Screenshot of a banner that lacks a button to close it]

Here is a screenshot of the whole page (mobile device)

[image]

And the transcribed version (without the link):

> got a question about the site itself? languagedesign.meta is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.

(Screenshots elsewhere on Meta make me think this happens to other sites in Private Beta as well, hence why I'm here on MSE)

I see why this banner is useful, but I know what Meta is, so can the banner be closable, please? Perhaps an <kbd>X</kbd> button on the right side of it I could press to close it...? I don't really see a good reason for it to be forever attached to the top of the page

Comment: Better see the banner in the context of the page itself, where does it appear? Top? Bottom? Please post full screenshot, or at least showing also part of the page itself. (e.g. if it's part of the page, it might not be considered a banner at all, hence no need to "close" it.)

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard It is at the top, but I added a screenshot

Answer (score 3):

I agree, this banner is not useful for Stack Exchange veterans who know the importance of a meta site. For now, I've solved it by adding the following line to my ad blocker (uBlock Origin):

```
languagedesign.stackexchange.com##aside.ps-static
```